# NoSuchMethodException QueryDSL with Spring Boot & Spring Data Mongo

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I am trying to implement Query DSL on my Spring Boot `2.0.4.RELEASE` app that uses Spring Data Mongo `2.0.4.RELEASE` & Gradle `4.10`.
I am using Spring Tool Suite for running it locally.

Did the following steps which I found from multiple sources including Spring data documentation:

- created `gradle/querydsl.gradle` which has below content to generate `Q` classes

```
    apply plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir "$buildDir/generated/source/apt/main"
            }
        }
    }

    querydsl {
        springDataMongo = true
        querydslSourcesDir = "$buildDir/generated/source/apt/main"
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:4.1.4"
        compileOnly "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4"
    }

    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
```

- Calling above gradle file from main `build.gradle` as shown below

```
    buildscript {

        ext { springBootVersion = "2.0.4.RELEASE" }

        repositories { mavenCentral() }

        dependencies {
            classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
            classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.9"
        }
    }

    plugins {
        id "java"
        id "eclipse"
        id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.4.RELEASE"
        id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories { mavenCentral() }

    dependencies {
        ...
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:${springBootVersion}")
        ...
    }

    apply from: 'gradle/querydsl.gradle'

    /* Added this because Eclipse was not able to find generated classes */
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['build/generated/source/apt/main','src/main/java']

    compileJava.dependsOn processResources
    processResources.dependsOn cleanResources
```

- After this updated the `Repository` annotated interface as below. Note: I also use [Fragment Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) **FragmentOrderRepository** for some custom queries.

```
    public interface OrderRepository<D extends OrderDAO>
            extends EntityRepository<D>, PagingAndSortingRepository<D, String>, FragmentOrderRepository<D>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<D> {}
```

- Then in controller created a `GET` mapping as shown here

```
    @RestController
    public class OrderController {
        @GetMapping(value="/orders/dsl", produces = { "application/json" })
        public ResponseEntity<List> getOrdersDSL(@QuerydslPredicate(root = OrderDAO.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, @RequestParam final MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters) {
            return (ResponseEntity<List>) orderService.getTools().getRepository().findAll(predicate, pageable);
        }
    }
```

- Then in my runner class I added `EnableSpringDataWebSupport` annotation

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
    public class SampleApp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SampleApp.class, args);
        }
    }
```

With this my app starts up without any errors but when I try hitting the path `http://localhost:5057/orders/dsl?email=test@test.com`

I get a `NoSuchMethodException` with message `No primary or default constructor found for interface com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate`.

Can anyone please help with some pointers to solve this issue?

It seems that parameters are not getting resolved to a type.

---- **UPDATE 09/19/19** ----

While debugging I found that a class `HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite` which finds ArgumentResolver for given `MethodParameter` from a List of **argumentResolvers**(of type `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`). This list does not contain `QuerydslPredicateArgumentResolver`. Hence it is not able to resolve the arguments.

This means `QuerydslWebConfiguration` which adds above resolver for `Predicate` type is not getting called, which in turn indicates that some **AutoConfiguration** is not happening.

Probably I am missing some annotation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake I was doing, was missing `EnableWebMvc` annotation on my `Configuration` annotated class.
Details are in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web) documentation.